# Using Git for local development with Subversion on the server?

Tags: git, svn

My enterprise use svn as a source control.

I would like to use git for my development (branches are so useful).

Do you think that there is no problem to checkout a svn project, to work with git in local for my development, and then, commit final changes with svn ?

Is there anything special to know when we work like this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`git-svn` worked nicely for me, but you have to be prepared that some of the more advanced features like branching (on the server) or Subversion externals might not be smooth. Test your use cases before you commit to anything.

Answer (score 1):

I have done this for more than a year, with little problem after I've gotten properly used to git. There are a few caveats to remember.

The first recommendation is to ALWAYS do "git svn dcommit --dry-run" before dcommit! Sometimes you don't realize that you are actually trying to push a ton of commits from a different branch, e.g. after a git merge.

Second, I usually for myself never work on the master branch. I work on a git branch and then REBASE onto the master branch before I want to put it in svn. Use rebase rather than merge, since svn needs to have a "linear history" on each branch/trunk/tag. Also, learn what rebase does and how to get out of trouble (e.g. rebase --abort). I always make a "backup branch" before I start rebasing stuff.

So, to push into svn, this is my workflow:

```
git checkout master
git svn rebase
git rebase <my_working_branch>
gitk (to review the changes)
git svn dcommit --dry-run
git svn dcommit
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use git-svn for this, it is available almost anywhere and works very well, even with very large svn repos. I found the following workflow useful when working with git and svn.

```
git svn clone svn+ssh://pathtorepo localname
git branch workingbranch
git co workingbranch ...
... work in branch
git co master
git merge workingbranch
git svn dcommit
```

This way you can commit, rollback, split, cherry-pick etc every way you want in the workingbranch, avoiding all problems subversion might have with a complicated git history.

If something changed on the svn server you just do the following to keep you master in line with all upstream commits (preserving the linear history of svn in your master branch):

```
git co master
git svn fetch
git svn rebase
```

And then you can use the normal git capabilities to get/merge/rebase commits into your workingbranch.